# Nginx reverse proxy for nodejs but static files after verification

Tags: node.js, nginx, nginx-location

I have configured my nginx server as such the static files are sent by nginx alone, otherwise if the uri does not exist, the request is routed to my nodejs server. But is it possible for nginx to check if the user is authenticated before serving a few html files such as admin related?
Can we designate static folders for nginx to have this check, if yes, serve the file. If no, redirect to login.

Comment: Thanks. Btw, it requires re building the server. Any other alternative?

Comment: Why? This module is buid by default in many distros. e.g. `nginx-full` in ubuntu/debian